# QMdiArea not adding subwindow

Tags: qt

I have an one function which is responsible for initializing custom widget and add it in to the MdiArea.When I call this at first time it is working fine.But if i will call again, it is initializing custom widget but not adding in into the MdiArea. I have mentioned that function here:-

```
void CArbWaveViewWidget::newFile()
{
     m_ptrWavePresenter = new CArbWavePresenter;

     QMdiSubWindow *subWindow1 = new QMdiSubWindow;
     subWindow1->setWidget(m_ptrWavePresenter->getTableView()); // getting customWidget
     qDebug()<<"Table View ==="<<m_ptrWavePresenter->getTableView();
     subWindow1->setAttribute(Qt::WA_DeleteOnClose);

     QMdiSubWindow *subWindow2 = new QMdiSubWindow;
     subWindow2->setWidget(m_ptrWavePresenter->getGraphView()); // getting customWidget
     qDebug()<<"Graph View ==="<<m_ptrWavePresenter->getGraphView();
     subWindow2->setAttribute(Qt::WA_DeleteOnClose);
     mdiArea->addSubWindow(subWindow1);
     mdiArea->addSubWindow(subWindow2); 
}
```

How can i solve this problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### 1. Declare your `QMdiSubWindow`

When you declare a `QMdiSubWindow`, give `mdiArea` as argument

```
QMdiSubWindow *subWindow = new QMdiSubWindow(mdiArea);
```

or you can use `setParent ( QWidget * parent )`

```
QMdiSubWindow *subWindow = new QMdiSubWindow();
subWindow->setParent(mdiArea);
```

#### 2. Create and add your `QWidget` in your `QMdiSubWindow`

```
QWidget *myWidget = new QWidget();
subWindow->setWidget(myWidget);
```

#### 3. Update `QMdiSubWindow` content

If you need to update the subwindow content, declare your `QMdiSubWindow` as class variable, initialize your `QMdiArea` and `QMdiSubWindow` and set `QWidget`

#### yourClass.h

```
class yourClass {

public:
    yourClass();
    void newFile();

private:
    QMdiArea *m_area;
    QMdiSubWindow *m_subWindow1, *m_subWindow2;

    void init();
};
```

#### yourClass.cpp

```
yourClass::yourClass()
{
    init();
}

void yourClass::init()
{
    m_area = new QMdiArea();
    m_subWindow1 = new QMdiSubWindow(m_area);
    m_subWindow2 = new QMdiSubWindow(m_area);
    // continue to init your QMdiSubWindow
}

void yourClass::newFile()
{
    // Set your QWidget (yourWidget) into your QMdiSubWindow
    m_subWindow1->setWidget(yourWidget);
    m_subWindow2->setWidget(anotherWidget);
}
```

Comment: First time it is working fine.If i will call second time that function ,it is not loading subwindow.

Comment: Yes, because you create all your context again. Just update your widget. For that, create your subwindows as class variables, and call a new function which update only your widgets.

Comment: It will work only for mdiarea with one subwindow. But in my case i want one mdiarea with multiplae subwindow with different custom widgets.

Comment: You can add another QMdiSubWindow in your class: m_subWindow2. If you don't know the number of QMdiSubWindow you will have, use a list or a vector.

Answer (score 1):

You need invoke method "show"

```
QMdiSubWindow *subWindow = new QMdiSubWindow();
subWindow->setParent(mdiArea);
subWindow->setWidget(yourWidget);
subWindow->show();
```

Comment: Strange, but it was my mistake indeed. I created a widget, then called addSubWindow and nothing... Thanks to your comment I recognized that my window is simply not visible.